Mass measurement in a Penning trap
My question is motivated by this paper. They are measuring the mass of a molecular ion in a Penning trap, and they are able to see a difference due to the fact that the molecule gets polarized (the motion is classical and non-relativistic). I was able to derive their result, for an induced electric dipole, using the Lagrangian:
$$L = mv^2/2 + \alpha E^2/2$$
where $\alpha$ is the polarization and $E$ is the electric field. If we use the fact that $E = vB$ we can see from the form of the Lagrangian, if we take the derivative with respect to $v$:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial v} = mv + \alpha v B^2 = (m+\alpha B)v$$
From this we get an effective mass of:
$$m+\alpha B^2$$
which is consistent with their result. However, I was wondering, if we assume that the molecule is highly (or fully) polarized and not just weakly, instead of $\alpha E^2/2$ we have simply $d E$, where $d$ is the intrinsic dipole moment of the molecule. However, assuming $d$ is constant, which is (very close to being) true for a fully polarized molecule, we have $d E = dvB$ which gives:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial v} = mv + dB$$
now we can't factor out $v$ anymore and thus it's not clear anymore how to count $dB$ towards the mass of the molecule. However, intuitively, I would expect that the higher the polarization, the higher the shift in the measured mass. What am I doing wrong, or how should I interpret the $dB$ term in this case? Thank you!

why did you think that your new case should be treated the same way as the old? i.e. why would it be considered via an effective mass rather than some other method?

I am not sure what you mean. Do you mean I shouldn't use the Lagrangian formalism in the second case? My main questions are, how should I interpret that dB term (i.e. can I think of it in terms of a more common quantity?) and is there a simple explanation as to why an induced dipole moment leads to a mass change, but a permanent one doesn't (the math shows so, but it is not intuitive to me why that is the case)

Just to clarify related to the first question, given that in the second case we can't think of it as an effective mass, would I be able to get a measurable signal in a Penning trap? And if so, what would that be?

Lagrangian is always helpful. I'm not familiar enough to state a simple explanation for that. However, it kinda looks more like a constant vector potential (remember, $\vec p=m\vec v-q\vec A$) or you might take it as an additive constant velocity $dB/m$ or what other method. In practice, you should be plotting the behaviour at varying conditions, and obtain one of those hyperbolic graphs as the interaction smoothly changes from effective mass behaviour to whatever other behaviour you choose to describe the permanent dipole.

I agree with @naturallyInconsistent: Not every systematic frequency shift can be modeled as an effective mass. While some shifts can be described as a change of "effective mass" or "effective charge", most can not be simplified that way and are just frequency shifts that you have to account for when calculating the free-space cyclotron frequency from your measurements.
